# Line's intersection with a boundary upto a certain a distance

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

According to Figure below, I wish to check if the line $L$ (sketched in grey) defined by a point ($x$,$y$) and angle $A$ with the vertical,within a distance $D$ in it's direction touches a discontinuous boundary defined by $y=d$ which is non-existent between x coordinates $c$ and $b$ .

Thus, the output should be in Boolean $true$ or $false$.

*Note:* If the line touches the defined boundary before the distance $D$ in it's direction, then also it should be considered and if it touches after the distance $D$ then not.

Please ask any inconsistencies if you think the question has.

One may also of course, think of line as line segment whose two points can calculated easily and then check intersection.

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @KittyL Please ask which part you didn't get. Sorry I am not from mathematical background, thus it may seem a weird formulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s=x+D\sin{A} $, $t=y+D\cos {A} $.

If ($s \leq c$ or $s \geq b$) and ($t\geq d$) true
else false.

Comment: shouldn't it be $t$ less than $d$?

Comment: It will not touch if t <d.

Comment: In my problem I consider the boundary only if touches before or at the distance the $d$ .

Comment: can you please reread the question with the above statement in the mind and notify if the sign needs to changed?

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand what do you mean by "before"? If it cross the solid black line, do you count it as true? If so, it should be $t\geq d$, because $t$ is the $y$ value of the end of the line segment. It is higher than that line if $t\geq d$. If it means it does not cross the solid line, then the sign should be reversed.

Comment: It's my fault I seem to have state it abruptly and weirdly. What I am trying to do find out is whether the line intersects with the boundary within the distance $d$. You may consider it as a person looking for obstacle in a given direction but only upto a certain distance.

Comment: Does the previous comment make sense? I think it should be reversed.

Comment: Let me clarify. Are the two solid black line segments obstacles? If that is so, then they are within the distance $D$ if $d\leq t$, that is, $t\geq d$, right? And your upward direction is positive $y$, right?

Comment: Yeah! Sorry I just got confused. Thanks for the patient explantation.